# Merge objects and add values with same key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to merge several objects that are in the same array and have only one object and I need to add the value of the elements that have the same key in different objects. This is one example of the arrays and objects I will be working with. I don't know what will be the keys so that complicates everything. I am using nodejs.

```js
var array = [{
    RT: 0.3396966806905289,
    Real: 0.03721461991442617,
    fired: 0.26138293747172237,
    'Real Madrid': 0.15767570563383954,
    Madrid: 0.2771992640023346,
    Zidane: 0.3218878635800967,
    'Florentino Perez': 0.31535141126767907,
    leave: 0.1632670522868711,
    manager: 0.12690962022792524,
    tancredipalmeri: 0.3218878635800967,
    Perez: 0.4543985280046692,
    Florentino: 0.44189852800466917
  },
  {
    Cannavaro: 0.2709492640023346,
    Ashley: 0.2771992640023346,
    'Ashley Cole': 0.15767570563383954,
    Casillas: 0.3896966806905289,
    Ronaldo: 0.22094926400233458,
    Zidane: 0.22094926400233458,
    Messi: 0.22094926400233458,
    Lampard: 0.22094926400233458,
    Iniesta: 0.22094926400233458,
    Terry: 0.2771992640023346,
    Henry: 0.19890866571173632,
    Cole: 0.22094926400233458,
    Ivanovic: 0.3218878635800967
  },
  {
    RT: 0.3396966806905289,
    effleurer: 0.22094926400233458,
    'n\'a': 0.2709492640023346,
    top: 0.13189246756926315,
    Zidane: 0.2709492640023346,
    entraineur: 0.22094926400233458,
    monde: 0.22094926400233458,
    au: 0.2271992640023346,
    'au monde': 0.20434237230050623,
    Mvssi10: 0.3218878635800967,
    JAMAIS: 0.2709492640023346
  },
  {
    RT: 0.3396966806905289,
    Real: 0.10790900513119943,
    FrenchRMCF: 0.3218878635800967,
    en: 0.2271992640023346,
    histoire: 0.2709492640023346,
    coach: 0.2271992640023346,
    au: 0.2271992640023346,
    Zidane: 0.22094926400233458,
    'en tant': 0.15767570563383954,
    tant: 0.22094926400233458
  }
]
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a free coding service. Please, show your best attempt at resolving your own issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce for that and iterate over the object keys of each object:

```js
const res = array.reduce((a, b) => {
    Object.keys(b).forEach(k => {
        a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + b[k];
    });
    return a;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const array = [
    {
        RT: 0.3396966806905289,
        Real: 0.03721461991442617,
        fired: 0.26138293747172237,
        'Real Madrid': 0.15767570563383954,
        Madrid: 0.2771992640023346,
        Zidane: 0.3218878635800967,
        'Florentino Perez': 0.31535141126767907,
        leave: 0.1632670522868711,
        manager: 0.12690962022792524,
        tancredipalmeri: 0.3218878635800967,
        Perez: 0.4543985280046692,
        Florentino: 0.44189852800466917
    },
    {
        Cannavaro: 0.2709492640023346,
        Ashley: 0.2771992640023346,
        'Ashley Cole': 0.15767570563383954,
        Casillas: 0.3896966806905289,
        Ronaldo: 0.22094926400233458,
        Zidane: 0.22094926400233458,
        Messi: 0.22094926400233458,
        Lampard: 0.22094926400233458,
        Iniesta: 0.22094926400233458,
        Terry: 0.2771992640023346,
        Henry: 0.19890866571173632,
        Cole: 0.22094926400233458,
        Ivanovic: 0.3218878635800967
    },
    {
        RT: 0.3396966806905289,
        effleurer: 0.22094926400233458,
        'n\'a': 0.2709492640023346,
        top: 0.13189246756926315,
        Zidane: 0.2709492640023346,
        entraineur: 0.22094926400233458,
        monde: 0.22094926400233458,
        au: 0.2271992640023346,
        'au monde': 0.20434237230050623,
        Mvssi10: 0.3218878635800967,
        JAMAIS: 0.2709492640023346
    },
    {
        RT: 0.3396966806905289,
        Real: 0.10790900513119943,
        FrenchRMCF: 0.3218878635800967,
        en: 0.2271992640023346,
        histoire: 0.2709492640023346,
        coach: 0.2271992640023346,
        au: 0.2271992640023346,
        Zidane: 0.22094926400233458,
        'en tant': 0.15767570563383954,
        tant: 0.22094926400233458
    }
]
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what the code does. @isanma. Real != Madrid and Mvssi10 != Messi... Maybe try to get better data first